# keyup event in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, ckeditor, dom-events, fckeditor

I'm using CKEditor and have an initEditor function that bootstraps all the event handler function of the editor instance like this:

btw, I'm using CoffeeScript

```
editor.on 'change', => ...
editor.on 'blur', => ...
editor.on 'key', => ...
```

and soon I found that the `key`event is actually `keydown`, I wonder there is a `keyup` event API, because this doesn't seem to work in my code:

```
editor.on 'keyup', => ...
```

and I got an error:

> TypeError: editor.onKeyup is not a function

in:

```
editor.onKeyup((e) => {...})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editor doesn't have a keyup event. If you want to catch it you should bind it to editors dom.

```
editor.document.on('keyup',function(){alert('kek')});
```

Comment: It solves the problem for sure, but without using the CKEditor API. Thanks anyway.